# How do I add a Laravel command in a subfolder?

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I'm trying to create a custom console command in Laravel 5.1 which does some helpful function for my project. I can do this fine when putting the console command in a file located at the base commands folder but not when I just to add a subdirectory.

```
'App\Console\Commands\SomeCustomCommandThatWorks',
'App\Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace\CustomCommandThatFails',
```

So how do I add my command like `MySubNameSpace\Command`?

Namespace doesn't appear to have any effect on this. The namespace of the command could be `App\Console\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand` or `App\Console\MyCommand` both fail if the file is located at `'App\Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand'`. The file also fails if located at `'App\Console\Commands\MyCommand'` with namespace `App\Console\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand`.

Right now I get this error.

```
Class App\Console\Commands\DeletePhantomServers does not exist
```

I have tried running composer dumpautoload but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must be tired. After reading Michael's answer I looked at the namespaces and realised I was just simply writing them wrong.

I was putting

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand;

class MyCommand ...
```

Where I needed to put

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace;

class MyCommand ...
```

Thanks for the help people :)

Answer (score 3):

According to autoloading standards, none of the combinations you have above will work. The namespace needs to be set according to the directory. So if you have the command in this folder

```
Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand
```

your namespace has to be

```
App\Console\Commands\MySubNameSpace\MyCommand
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply michael. You made me realise my mistake.